# How do I unlock the "Meat 4 Evar" challenge in "The Binding of Isaac"?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I've had Wrath of the Lamb for a week, and everywhere I search, I can't find the answer. Please help!

Comment: As far as I can tell, all challenges are unlocked from the start, just click the "challenges" item at the title screen. Are you sure you don't mean the achievement?

Comment: @Wilerson Actually, I believe he means, "How do I *beat* the challenge", since the Meat 4 Ever challenge is, as you mentioned, available from the start.

Comment: @Kyler Can you clarify exactly what information you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to **access** the *Meat 4 Evar* challenge, the answer is that you can select it at any time once you have Wrath of the Lamb

If you are asking how to **complete** the challenge, the answer is that you have to play through as normal and defeat Mom's Heart ([as the wiki says](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Challenges))

Comment: Link is broken. :(